# Possible to unit test a WebRequest class?

Tags: unit-testing, unity-game-engine

I tried to run Unit test on a class calling webRequest function, but it seems it never return the output:

```
        UnityWebRequest _www = UnityWebRequest.Get(url);
        Debug.Log("here");
        yield return _www.Send();
        Debug.Log("here2") //This is not printed
```

Comment: Unit testing unity functions is notoriously hard to do. Ususally I recommend splitting your business logic out in to a DLL that is just NetStandard2.0 that you can import in to Unity and put the code you would like to test in there.

Comment: @Scott "Unit testing unity functions is notoriously hard to do." That sure sounds ironic. +1